# ...modal is not a function

Tags: javascript, c#, controller

Estoy creando un reporte a partir de 3 parametros, donde despues va a el controller y hace la consulta y lo demas, en lo que se consultan los datos,aparece un modal que dice "Espere un momento",y una vez generado este desaparece,no tengo problema con crear este reporte,pero la primera vez funciona, la segunda vez que se presiona el boton "crear reporte", cambiando algun parametro , me marca error de `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function`

y es que para poder volver a consultar un reporte, se debe recargar la pagina, en vez de que se pueda realizar en ese mismo momento

```
function reporte() {
    var p1= document.getElementById("p1").value;
    var p2= document.getElementById("p2").value;
    var p3= document.getElementById("p3").value;

    $('#modal').modal('show'); //aqui da error la segunda vez


    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/Reporte/reporte?p1=' + p1+ '&p2=' + p2+ '&p3=' + p3,
        data: "",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "html"
    })
        .done(function (data) {
           
            $('#modal').modal('hide');

                
        })
}
```

Estas son mis referencias en el html

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css" />
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Pon el HTML del modal...pero casi apostaría que te falta `id=modal`

Comment: Hola cosito, si quitas el modal, puedes consultar dos veces?.